# What are the classes that can be played as the Tank role?

Tags: ragnarok-online-2

I'm about to create a new character in RO2 and I want to play the Tank role. I was going to create a `SWORDMAN - Warrior` because this part of his description

> Warriors are experienced mercenaries who have honed their skills on
>   countless battlefields.
>
> They carry great swords and **are capable of skillfully defending
>   themselves from enemy attacks.** Their experience allows them to mow
>   down enemies on the battlefield as though it were second nature.

But, the `SWORDMAN - Knight` has a good point too

> Knights are heavily trained through the Prontera Knights’ strict
>   education and strongly values rules and principles.
>
> They know how to handle ‘auras’ skillfully through systematic battle
>   training and also **can use their shields as a battle skill.**

Being able to do it, should show a "off-tank" type, in my opinion.

---

Then I asked a friend of mine and he said that besides this two options there are also the `ARCHER - Beastmasters` and the `Acolyte - Monk` that are being used as tank.

---

It's true this affirmation or even viable? Who is the "true" tank on RO2?

[Class list](http://ro2.playpark.net/game-info/class/)